# How can I populate each element in XML file to each Textbox field

Tags: xml, jquery

I have an XML file from Webservice. I'd like populate each element in that XML file to each TextBox. For example, XML file above has 4 elements and then I populate 4 elements that to 4 TextBox field. Anyone know how to resolve this please give me a hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do the parsing.. [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) is the API with an example

[here](http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/) is the example

[here](http://jparse.kylerush.net/demo) is a jquery plugin which can help with the parsing

Comment: Firstly, many thanks for your hepl. For example, I have XML file as below: <Table>
    <szCustomerCategoryTypeCode>12</szCustomerCategoryTypeCode>
    <szName>airline/hotel</szName>
    <szDescription>airline/hotel</szDescription>
    <bShopperID>-1</bShopperID>
  </Table>

Comment: As You can see above XML file has 4 elements. And I have 4 Textbox field to populate value from that XML file. So, I want to populate 4 value elements from XML file corresponding 4 Textbox field. Now, I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: And I have finished parse it. Now, I just want to get value from 4 value XML element above and then populate it to 4 Textbox field.

Comment: the example here does exactly that (well almost) http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/ , it shows how to extract a specific value from an XML.. you can set the value to a textbox using `$('#textBoxId').val(valueReadFromXml);`

Comment: Continue above problem, how can I populate value return from XML file into a List or Array in jquery. and How to loop using jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: please go through jquery.. this will help you with looping and iterating.. http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/